# How to find intersection point of opposite lines of two lines

Tags: javascript, intersection, trigonometry, line-intersection

I am trying to find intersection point of opposite lines of two lines:

[image]

```
var ax=0.00, ay=0.50 ;
var bx=1.00, by=1.00 ;
var cx=2.00, cy=0.25 ;
```

But I am very confused about finding an opposite of a line.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/digerkam/3eL8x6jn/) which points are converted between 0.0-1.0

So how to find that intersection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of clearing out your code a bit and adding a few objects in order to make recollection of data a bit easier. Added: `Point`, `Line` objects and an associated method `draw()` on both of them.

In order to do this, you first need to calculate the median point. This is pretty easy, with point `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` for your line, the median point is `( (a+c)/2, (b+d)/2 )`. This will be where your opposite line starts from.

From there, you can calculate the opposite gradient by taking the gradient of your line (`grad = (d-b)/(a-c)`) and working out `-1/grad` (since perpendicular lines have opposite gradients). This is the `opposite()` function I defined.

From here, you have your two opposite lines, you just need to find the intersection. You have both equations for both lines (since you know that a line is `y = g*x + r` where `g` is the gradient and `r` is the y-value at origin), so you can easily figure out the value where `(x,y)` is the same on both lines. If you can't, go on the [maths stackexchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com) and post *that* question there.

```js
function Point(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Point.prototype.draw = function(color="blue") {
  var diff = 0.0125 ;
  (new Line(this.x-diff, this.y-diff, this.x-diff, this.y+diff)).draw("normal", color);
  (new Line(this.x-diff, this.y+diff, this.x+diff, this.y+diff)).draw("normal", color);
  (new Line(this.x+diff, this.y+diff, this.x+diff, this.y-diff)).draw("normal", color);
  (new Line(this.x+diff, this.y-diff, this.x-diff, this.y-diff)).draw("normal", color);
}

function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  this.point1 = new Point(x1, y1);
  this.point2 = new Point(x2, y2);
}

Line.prototype.draw = function(style="normal", color="black") {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.save();
  if (style == "dashed-back") {
   ctx.setLineDash([5,3]); }
  ctx.strokeStyle = color ;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(xp(this.point1.x), yp(this.point1.y));
  ctx.lineTo(xp(this.point2.x), yp(this.point2.y));
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
  return this;
}
Line.prototype.intersect = function(otherLine) {
 var grad1 = (this.point2.y - this.point1.y)/(this.point2.x - this.point1.x);
  var grad2 = (otherLine.point2.y - otherLine.point1.y)/(otherLine.point2.x - otherLine.point1.x);
  var remainder1 = this.point1.y - this.point1.x * grad1;
  var remainder2 = otherLine.point1.y - otherLine.point1.x * grad2;
  var x = (remainder2 - remainder1)/(grad1 - grad2);
  var y = grad1 * x + remainder1;
  return new Point(x, y);
}
Line.prototype.opposite = function(style = "normal", color = "Black") {
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.save();
  var midway = new Point((this.point1.x + this.point2.x)/2, (this.point1.y + this.point2.y)/2);
  var invgrad = -1 * 1/(this.point2.y - this.point1.y)/(this.point2.x - this.point1.x);
  return new Line(midway.x - 100, midway.y - 100*invgrad, midway.x+100, midway.y + 100 * invgrad);
}

// Normalize points for normal plot
function xp (x) { return x*300+50 ; }
function yp (y) { return 450-(y*300) ; }

// Write a text
function text (str,x,y,size=12,color="black") {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = size+"px Arial" ;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillText(str,xp(x),yp(y));
  ctx.restore();
}

// Init guides
function init () {
  new Line(0, 0, 0, 1).draw("dashed-back", "#888");
  new Line(0, 1, 3, 1).draw("dashed-back", "#888");
  new Line(3, 1, 3, 0).draw("dashed-back", "#888");
  new Line(1, 0, 1, 1).draw("dashed-back", "#888");
  new Line(2, 0, 2, 1).draw("dashed-back", "#888");
  text("1",-0.05,0.95)
  text("0",-0.05,-0.05)
  text("1",1,-0.05)
  text("2",2,-0.05)
  text("3",3,-0.05)
}

init();

var ax=0.00, ay=0.50 ;
var bx=1.00, by=1.00 ;
var cx=2.00, cy=0.25 ;
var dx=3.00, dy=0.75 ;

new Point(ax,ay).draw("red");
new Point(bx,by).draw("red");
new Point(cx,cy).draw("red");
new Point(dx,dy).draw("red");

var line1 = new Line(ax, ay, bx, by).draw("normal", "blue");
var line2 = new Line(bx, by, cx, cy).draw("normal", "blue");
var line3 = new Line(cx, cy, dx, dy).draw("normal", "blue");
line2.opposite().draw("normal", "red");
line1.opposite().draw("normal", "orange");
line1.opposite().intersect(line2.opposite()).draw("normal", "purple");
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="600">
```

---

**Caveat**: I had a pretty big error in my code - the gradient for opposite lines was miscalculated as `-1 * grad` as opposed to `-1 / grad`.

Comment: @JonasWilms the triviality of it is one of the two reasons I didn't put it in the answer - the other being that it's more readable with full LaTeX support, something which SO doesn't have but math SE does.